# ServiceStack Grpc - Generate proto file without invoking types/proto endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, grpc

I have a .Net Core 3.1 Grpc application created using **ServiceStack** framework. ServiceStack provides a way to auto-generate .proto files through [/types/proto](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Extensions/GrpcFeature.cs#L451) endpoint. It internally invokes [GrpcProtoGenerator](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Extensions/GrpcFeature.cs#L468) class to generate .proto file. It also requires [AppHost](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/ab7a3c571d0653ea3813013bea62c1fe3f610674/src/ServiceStack/AppHostBase.NetCore.cs#L28), [IHostingEnvironment](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/ab7a3c571d0653ea3813013bea62c1fe3f610674/src/ServiceStack/AppHostBase.NetCore.cs#L117) and other objects to generate it.

However, I want to manually invoke GrpcProtoGenerator class for file generation instead of invoking /types/proto endpoint, but it's throwing an error, saying IHostingEnvironment is null. Is there a way to manually invoke the class by providing all necessary objects?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of ServiceStack Features especially ServiceStack Services require a fully initialized AppHost. You can checkout at [GrpcTests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Extensions.Tests/GrpcTests.cs#L367) for an example of how to initialize a grpc-enabled AppHost in code, after the AppHost is initialized you should then be able to invoke `GrpcProtoGenerator` manually.

This is what the `/types/proto` Service uses to generate the proto for all your gRPC Services:

```
var typesConfig = NativeTypesMetadata.GetConfig(request);
var metadataTypes = NativeTypesMetadata.GetMetadataTypes(Request, typesConfig);
var proto = new GrpcProtoGenerator(typesConfig).GetCode(metadataTypes, base.Request);
return proto;
```

The GrpcTests also shows examples of creating a proto for adhoc types:

```
static string GetServiceProto<T>()
    => GrpcConfig.TypeModel.GetSchema(MetaTypeConfig<T>.GetMetaType().Type, ProtoBuf.Meta.ProtoSyntax.Proto3);

    var schema = GetServiceProto<CustomRequestDto>();
    Assert.AreEqual(@"syntax = ""proto3"";

package ServiceStack.Extensions.Tests;
message CustomRequestDto {
       int32 PageName = 42;
       string Name = 105;
    }
    ", schema);
```